# Facebook PHP SDK Version 3, Event throwing exception

Tags: php, facebook

Im not sure why as the code hasnt changed, but calling the following code used to work (make event and then get the event id

```
$result = $facebook->api('/{page_id}/events', "POST", $query);
//var_dump($result);
$eid = $result['id'];
```

Now weirdly the event is created, but it also throws an exception

```
[message] => Unsupported post request. 
[type] => GraphMethodException 
[code] => 100
```

The event is created fine and visible etc. but I cant seem to get the event id for further processing (inviting people to the event)

Im looking to upgrade to version 4, but cant currently due to running PHP 5.3

Any suggestions on how to make version 3 work as intended and not throw an exception ?

Comment: Creating events using the API is removed in API v2.0 and later

Comment: the event is created with this code though ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/events

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

Maybe you are using a v1.0 App, but it should not be possible to create events anymore. And it´s not possible to invite users to an event either:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/invited

> You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API.

**Here´s a very important link to the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog**

Comment: the event is created. and ive created many events though the sdk its not through the graph api

Comment: so are you using a v1.0 app? because if you are able to do it in a new one, it sounds like a bug - it should not be possible anymore.

Comment: what do you mean "not through the graph api"? the sdk is using the graph api.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was thinking of something else. Yes its though Graph. Im using 3.2.2 and have always used this. The event gets created no problem. The return call started failing about 1 month ago

Comment: you can use any API version with the SDK 3.2.2. - make sure you understand the difference between Graph API and SDK - the last one it just a possibility to use the Graph API.